# RecyclerView: add variable spacing below last element

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

how can i add spacing below the last element of a RecyclerView, where the height of the spacing is exactly as high as the height of the RecyclerView - so that I can scroll to the bottom of the RecyclerView and the last element is displayed at the top of the RecyclerView?

Basically I want to be able to keep scrolling until the last element of my RecyclerView is displayed at the very top:

```
+------------+    +------------+
| 1. element |    | 5. element |
| 2. element |    |            |
| 3. element |    |            |
| 4. element |    |            |
| 5. element |    |            |
+------------+    +------------+
```

I found solutions where I add a fixed padding to the RecyclerView with the attribute cliptopadding=false:

```
android:padding="4dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

However this only adds a fixed dp of padding. And since I don't know the height of my RecyclerView I cannot use a fixed padding of xx dp.

How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could detect the last item in the list and when you bind data to it you also set its bottom margin to the lists height - the item height.

Comment: I guess your correct, but how can I get the height of my RecyclerView from inside onBindViewHolder() in the RecyclerViewAdapter class?

Comment: The onBindViewHolder method is in your adapter class. A simple solution is to pass the height of your recyclerview into your adapters constuctor.